# Does anyone know how to plot the first 30 terms of this equation in Python?

Tags: python

Does anyone know how to plot the first 30 terms of this equation in Python? 
a(0)=3
a(n)=0.5a(n-1)+10

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. People are here to help you but you have to make some effort. Can you show what you've tried already?

Comment: To get you started, you may want to use a for loop to loop through the 30 terms.

Answer (score 0):

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_value(n):
    if n <= 0:
        a = 3
    else:
        a = 0.5*get_values(n-1)+10
    return a

output =[]
for n in range(29):
   output.append({'y': get_value(n)})

graph_table = pd.DataFrame(output)
graph_table.plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with Matplotlib

```
from matplotlib import pyplot


def f(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 3
    else:
        return 0.5 * f(x - 1) + 10


x = range(30)
pyplot.plot(x, [f(i) for i in x ], 'o')
pyplot.show()
```

You may want to use linspace from NumPy to get a smoother plot.